# Facial Recognition + Database + Compare & Identify - is it complicated?

Tags: machine-learning, facial-recognition, pattern-recognition

The last week I've been looking for freelancers who are able to do this project for me but they weren't that experienced in it, so I would like to know whether my idea is complicated or is it their lake of experience.

**Scenario:**

**1.** The facial recognition system will be installed on a vertical screen where a camera would be attached to it and it will be assigned on the entrance of the room.

**2.** Once a visitor come to the entrance, and looks at the screen, a text on the screen would say: " Welcome! It seems like it's your first visit! Please enter your name then a keyboard should popup"

**3.** The visitor would enter his first name into the keyboard, and it would be saved alongside his face in the database, and it would say thank you, {name}.

**4.** If the same visitor visits again, the system should say: " Welcome back {name}, happy to see you again"!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of accuracy/speed you want your system to have, you could try using an [existing python AP](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition)I. First thing I found on google, the README looks adapted to your project. Otherwise ask your question with more accurate wanted specifications perhaps.